# How could we can delete all tables under the database in databricks notebook using sql?

Tags: sql, database, pyspark, databricks, aws-databricks

How could we can delete all tables under the database in databricks notebook using sql??

Answer (score 4):

You can use the DROP SCHEMA statement. It will drop all tables from the schema

```
DROP SCHEMA schema_name CASCADE
```

for reference check the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-drop-schema.html)

Comment: it will fail with this syntax :-)

Comment: better? :) :) :)

Comment: often, the next question is "how to restore deleted tables" ;-)